# Elliptic regularity of second order pseudos

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $M$ be a compact manifold. Choose a point $q \in M$. Let $P$ be a second order positive self-adjoint  pseudodifferential operator such that $\text{Spec}(P) \subset (0, \infty)$. Also, we know that $P$ is elliptic on $M \setminus \{q\}$. Can we say that $(Pu, u) \cong \Vert u\Vert^2_{H^1}$, or at least $(P(\varphi u), \varphi u) \cong \Vert \varphi u\Vert_{H^1}^2$ for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty (M \setminus \{q\})$? If $P$ were elliptic on $M$, this is standard material. But here the lack of ellipticity at a point is throwing me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the answer to your second question is yes.

Let $\varphi\in C^\infty_c(M\backslash\{q\})$ be given. Choose a function $\tau\in C^\infty_c(M,[0,1])$ which is equal to $1$ in a neighbourhood of $q$ and which has a support disjoint from the support of $\varphi$. Put a Riemannian metric on $M$, so that we have the negative Laplacian $-\Delta$, a positive elliptic second order differential operator. Let $\widetilde{P}:=(1-\tau)P+\tau (-\Delta)$. Then $\widetilde P$ is a positive second order pseudodifferential operator that is elliptic everywhere on $M$ and one has$$\widetilde P\varphi u=(1-\tau)P\varphi u+\tau (-\Delta)\varphi u=(1-\tau)P\varphi u=P\varphi u -\tau P\varphi u\qquad \forall\;u\in H^2(M),$$
because $\Delta$ is a local operator. Now, as the supports of $\varphi$ and $\tau$ are disjoint, one gets
\begin{align}(P(\varphi u),\varphi u)_{L^2(M)}&= (\widetilde{P}(\varphi u),\varphi u)_{L^2(M)}+(\tau P\varphi u,\varphi u)_{L^2(M)}\\&=
(\widetilde{P}(\varphi u),\varphi u)_{L^2(M)}+(P\varphi u,\underbrace{\tau\varphi}_{\equiv0} u)_{L^2(M)}\\&=(\widetilde{P}(\varphi u),\varphi u)_{L^2(M)}.\end{align}
Thus, the problem for functions supported away from $q$ reduces to the situation of an elliptic operator, for which the result is standard, as you say.

Comment: Nice answer. Since the two norms are equivalent with equivalence constants independent of $\varphi$, is it possible to make a limiting argument to answer the first question affirmatively?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: One last detail: could you please elaborate a little on why $C^\infty_c(M\setminus \{q\})$ is dense in $H^2(M)$? It seems to me (intuitively) that any sequence of approximating functions would have to go to $0$ sharply at $q$ resulting in a high gradient norm. What am I missing here?

Comment: On second thoughts, in dimensions $n \geq 3$, I am convinced. But the case $n = 2$ seems a bit odd to me.

Comment: Also, it is not clear to me that $\varphi_n \to 1_M$ in $H^2(M)$-norm implies $\varphi_n u \to u$ in $H^1(M)$-norm. Is this obvious?

Comment: Rather, it is better to take a sequence $u_n \in H^2(M) \cap C^\infty_c(M \setminus \{q\})$ such that $u_n \to u$ in $H^2$-norm. I hope you don't mind my nitpicking.

Comment: Well, your ``nitpicking'' was absolutely right, since I made a mistake. I thought that the density of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in $H^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ would directly imply the density of $C_c^\infty(M\backslash\{q\})$ in $H^2(M)$, but that's not the case. And also it does not necessarily hold that $\varphi_n\to 1_M$ in $H^2(M)$ implies $\varphi_n u\to u$ in $H^1(M)$. So I think only the first part of my answer is correct, and I don't know anymore whether the answer to your first question is in fact affirmative. I edited the answer accordingly. Of course now my answer is not complete anymore.

Comment: Also, another point: since the construction of $\widetilde{P}$ depends on $\tau$, and hence $\varphi$, should one be concerned that the constants of equivalence in $(\widetilde{P} u, u) \cong \Vert u\Vert^2_{H^1}$ are dependent on $\varphi$?